# Grignard with nitrile: why is the imine protonated twice?

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

[image]

Steps 2 and 3 in the picture show the imine being protonated twice to form the iminium ion in step 4. I'm a little confused as to why the second protonation occurs; does the imine after step 2 still have basic tendencies?

Comment: The imine is a stable compound, if you work up carefully you can isolate it. This mechanism assumes that you want to make the ketone so it shows the hydrolysis to the ketone as well as the Grignard addition.

Comment: @Waylander that makes sense, thank you!